# Obscure fields from django GET request

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am fetching the relatedfiles_set in my ControlsSerializer, but I would like to obscure the uploaded_by_user_id and organization_id for security purposes. I still need those fields in the RelatedFileSerializer for when I create new relatedfiles, but I don't want them to show during GET requests. Is there any way I can hide these fields without creating separate serializers for these two types of requests?

```
class RelatedFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RelatedFiles
        fields = ('control', 'file', 'uploaded_by_user_id', 'organization_id', 'note', 'uploaded_at')

class ControlsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    relatedfiles_set = RelatedFileSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Controls
        fields = ('relatedfiles_set', 'id', 'sorting_id',  'requirement', 'requirement_section', 'requirement_subsection',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare those fields you want to "hide" as `write_only` fields, the [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) has an example regarding that, you could declare your `RelatedFileSerializer` as:

```
class RelatedFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RelatedFiles
        fields = ('control', 'file', 'uploaded_by_user_id', 'organization_id', 'note', 'uploaded_at')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'uploaded_by_user_id': {'write_only': True},
            'organization_id': {'write_only': True},
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! I had seen reference to that, but couldn't figure out the exact implementation.